# What is the default installation directory for products installed from Eclipse Marketplace?

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to install a new server (WebSphere Application Server 7) in Eclipse (Kelper).

I've downloaded the product from the Eclipse Marketplace.

When I get to the following screen, I'm not sure where it was installed.  When I try to give it a directory I think might be it, it doesn't like it.  Any ideas?

[image: New Server]

Here is my installed page from marketplace:

[image: Marketplace]

Comment: I've never you used websphere before but are you sure you downloaded an actual websphere server from the marketplace, and not just some adapter plugin that allows you to use a websphere server with eclipse?

Comment: Good question.  I've included a screenshot of my "Installed" tab from Marketplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog is asking where you installed WebSphere Server, not where you installed the tools you downloaded from the marketplace.  The tools let you interact with the WebSphere server.  The Server itself is the actual runtime platform for your web apps and other J2EE components.